# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exception for Loading Tabs in an Activity

Tags: java, android, libs

I try to implement an activity that contains some tab views, but when I want to run the project, I got following Exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 com.example.activities.TabBarActivity$SectionsPagerAdapter
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at
 com.example.activities.TabBarAcitivity.loadMainTabs(TabBarAcitivity.java:129)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at 
 com.example.activities.TabBarAcitivity.access$1(TabBarAcitivity.java:122)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at 
 com.example.activities.TabBarAcitivity$ServiceMessageHandler.handleMessage(TabBarAcitivity.java:370)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I searched and googled about this exception a lot, but I could not find a useful and detailed solution for my problem. Most of the responses in case of fixing this issue was about Changing 'Order and Export' list ([project] Properties) and checking or unchecking them to solving this problem. Here is a capture of my project Properties:

[image]

Please guide me, that what can be the exact reason of this exception and also please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: remove android supports from the java build paths and refer the appcompact library. also 'tick' android dependencies and private libraries and move to top. then clean and build

Comment: I just did all instructions you wrote for me in the previous comment. Now I got another problem about `missing android-support-v7-appcompat.jar ` in my dependencies. What can I do for solving this problem?

Comment: property->Android->add library ->support appcompact->ok then click apply button. agin any problem found replace your appcompact lib and try again

Comment: I added support appcompat 7 library again and again, but I catch the same error, while I checked my sdk/ extras directory, and I found android-support-v7-appcompat.jar there. I confused about this issue. please help me to concur it.

Comment: for missing problem remove all your reference lib and click the apply button. then again add the libs and click apply. this work for me